# Logged in user name and last name wont show on the navbar

Tags: php, html, authentication

I'm a beginner in php and I want the name and last name of the logged in user to show on my navbar. Instead it shows the php code. This is my code inside the navbar.

```
<?php 
    echo "<p>" . $_SESSION['vorname'] . " " . $_SESSION['nachname'] . "</p>";
?>
```

This is what it shows instead.

[The output on the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Yze.png)

[I changed the file extension to .php and this is what it outputs now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNWqI.png)

Comment: Is this code saved in a file with `.php` extension? Do other PHP scripts on the same site work?

Comment: No, this code is saved in the index.html file and yes the other PHP scripts work properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The notice suggests that session is not started in your script, so you need to call `session_start()` prior to accessing `$_SESSION` variable. It would also be wise to check whether the user is logged in or not:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['vorname'], $_SESSION['nachname'])) {
      echo "<p>" . $_SESSION['vorname'] . " " . $_SESSION['nachname'] . "</p>";
    } else {
      echo "<p>No user is logged in</p>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I added the changes you suggested. It doesnt work and it shows the first output again.

Comment: The first output - do you mean it shows PHP code in the page? If so, you really need to save it in a file with `.php` extension, otherwise it would work.

Comment: Yes it shows the php code in the page. I have saved them in a file .php but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well that's a pity, but the code is [correct](https://3v4l.org/vUP9J). If it does not work, you are probably calling it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

PHP-Files have to be saved with the `.php` file extension to be executed. I suppose the other working files all have the right file extension?

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

You have to save all files with php code as `.php`.

Inside them you can use clean HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

or HTML mixed with PHP:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php echo '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>'; ?>
    <?php echo '<p>You are logged as '.$_SESSION['vorname'].' '.$_SESSION['nachname'].'</p>'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And remember to use PHP server (XAMPP, WAMP) on localhost - PHP files will not work if you open them directly in web browser (i.e. `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/hello/index.php` )

Comment: So if you get `undefined variable _SESSION` error it means that you didn't started a session and variable is unknown. 

Put `<?php session_start(); ?>` in first line (it must be first line) of your `php` file. 

Next put this code: 
`<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['vorname'])){
$_SESSION['vorname']='';
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['nachname'])){
$_SESSION['nachname']='';
}
?>`
This code means: if variable doesn't exists, make it.